# Can I distribute my software using a license other than EPL if I use an EPL dependency in the project?

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, epl

I'm planning to work on a library which uses [Clojure](https://github.com/clojure/clojure) as a dependency. I'm planning to add it as a Maven dependency so I won't modify anything in Clojure, I'll just use the binary as-is.

The [EPL FAQ](https://eclipse.org/legal/eplfaq.php#USEEPL) states than I **can** use EPL to distribute my code but I'm more interested in the opposite: can I use MIT or Apache license for my OSS project (non-copyleft) if I have an EPL binary dependency?

Comment: @whomever who downvoted: care to explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EPL isn't a copyleft license. The EPL license doesn't claim to apply to program modules that are linked to the EPL code.

You can choose any compatible  license you like for your own code.
The Apache and MIT licenses are both compatible with the EPL, but the GPL isn't.

Comment: I'm not really versed with licenses so after reading the FAQ I felt that you are obliged to use EPL if you touch the code but if you only link you can use whatever you like but I was not sure. So thanks!

Comment: I'd say this is a limited or weak copyleft rather than non-copyleft in that it applies only to the EPL-licensed code, right?